# How to pass a session id to the next page from foreach loop

Tags: php, session, foreach

I was facing like id overwriting problem when I tried to pass:

```
$_session['ads_id'] = $row['ads_id'];
```

to the next page using:

```
echo $_session['ads_id'];
```

I then define an array like:

```
$session['ads_id] = array();
```

and

```
$session['ads_id'][] = $row['ads_id'];
```

When I echo it like:

```
$ads_id =  implode($_SESSION["ads"]);
```

so it was showing all the `ads_id` like `112,113,114` and not specific linked with user_id.

Then I defined a `foreach` loop like:

```
foreach($_SESSION['ads'] as $ads_id) {
}
```

Now I don't know how to pass it to the next page? If someone clicks ads_id 113 from the table and it shows only 113 and not other ids.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ads where user_id ='{$_SESSION[ "user_id" ]}'";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
$ads_id = array();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
$_SESSION['ads'] = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {


 $_SESSION['ads'][]= $row['ads_id'];            

foreach($_SESSION['ads'] as $ads_id) {
}

echo $ads_id ////  Here I don't want to echo it, I want to pass to the next page
```

I want to pass the $ads_id to update.php from here.
I tried like this on update.php which is not working.

```
 SESSION_START();
 echo $ads_id ;
echo $_SESSION['ads_id'];
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't really get what your issue is? If you store the id's as an array in the session, you can do what ever you want with them on the other page. Please edit your question to explain in more details what you're actually are trying to do.

Comment: How many `ads_id`s are linked to one `user_id`? Is it one or can it be several?

Comment: PHP variables are case-sensitive so `$_SESSION` and `$_session` are entirely different variables ([demo](https://3v4l.org/CumLW)).

Comment: There are several ads_id linked to a user id. My question is simple I don't really know how to pass the variable $ads_id  from for each loop to the next page. As you can see I have displayed variable $ads_id from foreach loop on welcome.php I want to pass it to update.php so how can I pass. I tried like session_start(); and then echo $ads_id on update.php but it was not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$_SESSION` variable will be accessible in all your other scripts as long as all other scripts starts with `session_start()`.

```php
<?php
session_start();

//...rest of the codes
```

Comment: I know how to start a session. Consider The code which I given above is welcome.php. now I want to pass the $ads_id to updatd.php, I tried like $_SESSION_START(); echo $ads_id but it was not working.